# A sci-fi-ish movie about toys coming to life I saw on TV when I was a kid

Tags: story-identification, soft-sci-fi, cyborg, toys

I've been looking for this movie for probably two decades - not because it's brilliant or anything, but just because I can't leave a mystery unsolved.

It was a movie about a kid who loved toys and had a massive bedroom full of them. Must have been one hell of a spoiled kid. Anyway, he talks to another kid at school who has only one toy - if I remember correctly it was some kind of sphere.

So the protagonist kid steals it for some reason I don't recall, perhaps to see what was so special about it, and it causes all of his toys to come to life and attack him.

I caught it on TV during kids' TV time, and it was pretty tolerable for the most part, although there's this bit where a cyborg woman with a weird drill hand or something shows up and tries to kill him - that bit definitely scared me a little bit, young as I was.

Yes this movie did exist, believe me, I saw it. Maybe it was a TV movie or something, now lost to time, and I'll never again know what it was called, but I post this in hope someone out there might know.

Comment: Speaking of evil spheres and spoiled children with too many toys; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silent_Night,_Deadly_Night_5:_The_Toy_Maker

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)